# How to remove leading whitespace from each line in a file

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
       for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

I want it to look like this (remove indentations):

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

How can this be done (using `sed` maybe?)?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
sed "s/^[ \t]*//" -i youfile
```

Warning: this will overwrite the original file.

Comment: FWIW, I couldn't get this (or anything similar) working on OS X Mavericks, now when I needed it. Running "perl -pe '<regexp>'" worked fine, though. I even tried adding the -E parameter to sed, which didn't help.

Comment: I can confirm that the sed on OS X Mavericks is broken w.r.t. every other unix-like OS.  It does not appear to allow matching of any escaped character inside character classes.

Comment: You may install gsed on OS X.

Comment: You can use ANSI-C quoting `$' '` on mac osx for it to interpret `\t` correctly. Must be single quotes, not double. `sed $'s/^[ \t]*//'` Also, mac osx's `sed` is not `gnu`, so a lot of the `gnu` features are not supported. @per @chris

Comment: Default `sed` on Mac expects a temp file to use for inline replacements. You can generally just add `''` after `-i` to satisfy this. The final command would be, `sed -i '' 's/\s*//' yourfile`

Comment: Just sayin', you are the first programmer I ever saw who used `-i` AFTER the RegEx arguments. That either proves that I am an insect among men or that you are superhuman. Frankly, I'm not sure which, but I feel like it's the latter. Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 32):

For this specific problem, something like this would work:

```
$ sed 's/^ *//g' < input.txt > output.txt
```

It says to replace all spaces at the start of a line with nothing. If you also want to remove tabs, change it to this:

```
$ sed 's/^[ \t]+//g' < input.txt > output.txt
```

The leading "s" before the / means "substitute". The /'s are the delimiters for the patterns. The data between the first two /'s are the pattern to match, and the data between the second and third / is the data to replace it with. In this case you're replacing it with nothing. The "g" after the final slash means to do it "globally", ie: over the entire file rather than on only the first match it finds.

Finally, instead of `< input.txt > output.txt` you can use the `-i` option which means to edit the file "in place". Meaning, you don't need to create a second file to contain your result. If you use this option you will lose your original file.

Comment: Not quite the direct answer, but solved the problem I was searching for. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You can use AWK:

```
$ awk '{$1=$1}1' file
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

#### sed

```
$ sed 's|^[[:blank:]]*||g' file
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

#### The shell's `while`/`read` loop

```
while read -r line
do
    echo $line
done <"file"
```

Comment: Your `sed` example worked for me where answers to other similar questions did not work. Thanks!

Comment: @ghostdog74 what is this kinda of expression ([[:blank:]]) called? I saw another example where people used [[:space:]] to remove leading whitespaces. Besides, blank, space, what other words can be used here? I just want to understand this usage. Thanks!

Comment: @olala I found this in the man pages for `tr`;  [:blank:] all horizontal whitespace, [:space:] all horizontal or vertical whitespace. So, if you use [[:space:]] it should not only remove the spaces and tabs, but also the newlines (\n) leaving you with a single line of text. Using [[:blank:]] will leave the newlines. Note that I haven't actually tried this with `sed` yet, but that is the action using `tr`

Comment: This is the command which worked for me on MacOS. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

This Perl code edits your original file:

```
perl -i -ne 's/^\s+//;print' file
```

The next one makes a backup copy before editing the original file:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 's/^\s+//;print' file
```

Notice that Perl borrows heavily from sed (and AWK).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
sed -e **'s/^[ \t]*//'**  name_of_file_from_which_you_want_to_remove_space > 'name _file_where_you_want_to_store_output'
```

**For example:**

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'  file1.txt > output.txt
```

**Note:**

`s/`: Substitute command ~ replacement for pattern (`^[ \t]*`) on each addressed line

`^[ \t]*`: Search pattern ( ^ – start of the line; `[ \t]*` match one or more blank spaces including tab)

`//`: Replace (delete) all matched patterns

Answer (score 1):

You can remove leading white space by below any command:

```
 - sed -i "s/\s*//" filename
 - sed -i "s/[[:space:]]*//"  filename        
 - sed -i "s/^\s*//"   filename
 - sed -i "s/[ \t]*//"  filename
```

If you want to remove blank line  you can try any one of the following command:

```
 - sed "/^$/d"  filename
```

If you want to delete any leading white space, tab or empty line in that case you can use below command:

```
sed  -i -e "/^$/d"   -i -e "s/^\s*//"  filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
user@host:~$ sed 's/^[\t ]*//g' < file-in.txt
```

Or:

```
user@host:~$ sed 's/^[\t ]*//g' < file-in.txt > file-out.txt
```

Comment: it will be shorter with -i(in-place) arg

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, if you are *editing* this file, you can probably highlight all the lines and use your un-tab button.

- In Vim, use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to highlight the lines, then press <kbd><<</kbd>
- If you're on a Mac, then you can use [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)), [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text), etc., then highlight with your mouse and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

I am not sure if there is some requirement that this must be done from the command line. If so, then :thumbs-up: to the accepted answer! =)

Comment: Prometheus, was your comment here intended for a different answer?