# How to output a simple list of Maven dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm trying to get a simple, machine-parsable list of dependencies from my POM. If I do:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:list -f sample.pom
```

I get a load of pointless `[INFO]` output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - my-group:my-project:jar:1.0
[INFO]    task-segment: [org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:list]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dependency:list {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    com.squareup.picasso:picasso:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO]    commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 11 14:06:05 GMT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/325M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
```

which I then have to manually scrape to get the info. If I add the `-q` switch

```
mvn -q org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:list -f sample.pom
```

I get a download progress message or nothing if it's already local (unless there's an error of course).

Is there really no way to execute the dependency list command, so it just outputs a simple list of downloaded dependencies? Something like:

```
> mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:list -f sample.pom
    com.squareup.picasso:picasso:jar:2.5.2:compile
    commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
>
```

Comment: Like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084669/how-to-generate-a-graph-of-the-dependency-between-all-modules-of-a-maven-project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to redirect the output of the [`maven-dependency-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to a file with the help of the [`outputFile`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html#outputFile) attribute:

> If specified, this parameter will cause the dependencies to be written to the path specified, instead of writing to the console.

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:list -f sample.pom -DoutputFile="..."
```

The plugin will create the file if it does not exist. If it already exists, the content will be overwritten (but this can be controlled by the [`appendOutput`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html#appendOutput) attribute).

This should give you a simple and parsable list of dependencies.

---

As a side-note, I notice you are using a very old version of the `maven-dependency-plugin` ([2.1 is dated January 2009](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1)). The latest is [2.10](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.10) at this time.

Comment: Thanks - the file output seems close enough for my needs. The plugin version was a typo!

Answer (score 4):

Building on the answer from Tunaki and combining with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7757228/1132806) to use stdout as a file, I get this:

```
> mvn -q org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:list \
  -f sample.pom -DoutputFile=>(cat)

The following files have been resolved:
   commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
   com.squareup.picasso:picasso:jar:2.5.2:compile

>
```

Not perfect - but a significant improvement for my purposes.

Comment: Use (tail -n +3) to get just the list. I also like to sort mine so I use (tail -n +3|sort)

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement to Faron's comment above

This will sort remove empty lines and leading whitespace indents

```
mvn -q org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:list -DoutputFile=>(tail -n +3|sort|awk 'NF'|sed "s/^[ \t]*//")
```

Example

```
❯ mvn -q org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:list -DoutputFile=>(tail -n +3|sort|awk 'NF'|sed "s/^[ \t]*//")
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-accessanalyzer:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-account:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-acm:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-acmpca:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-alexaforbusiness:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-amplifybackend:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-amplify:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-amplifyuibuilder:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-api-gateway:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-apigatewaymanagementapi:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-apigatewayv2:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-appconfigdata:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-appconfig:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-appflow:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-appintegrations:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-applicationautoscaling:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-applicationcostprofiler:jar:1.12.261:compile
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-applicationinsights:jar:1.12.261:compile
```

Without the sed and awk to remove the empty lines and leading whitespace it would look like this.

```
❯ mvn -q org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:list -DoutputFile=>(tail -n +3|sort)

   com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-accessanalyzer:jar:1.12.261:compile
   com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-account:jar:1.12.261:compile
   com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-acm:jar:1.12.261:compile
   com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-acmpca:jar:1.12.261:compile
   com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-alexaforbusiness:jar:1.12.261:compile
   com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-amplifybackend:jar:1.12.261:compile
```

Reference for sed command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2310620
Reference for awk command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29549497